# jQuery won't load in my html file or just doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I have been creating a kind of a simple personal web page, and I started with a page that shows a 3x3 image collage inside a div, and I want that div the collage is in to animate and expand it's width so that I can add the description for each image in the right side, when an image is clicked.

Anyways, I have made a script for that, which I believe should work correctly. However, when I load the page in my browser and click on the image, the div does not expand.

Maybe the problem is that I just didn't link the script file or the jQuery library correctly? Anyways, here are the HTML and jQuery codes, so can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Music</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="mosaic">
            <a href="#"><img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/wsws.jpg"></a>
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/kida.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/spirit.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/texas.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/floating.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/ashes.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/dataplex.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/twinfantasy.jpg">
            <img class="item" src="images/music/thumbs/usa.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery (script.js):

```
var main = function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        $(".panel").animate({
            width:"900px";
        },600);
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console, and are you running this page from a server or locally? Also you have a typo. No `;` in `"900px";`

Comment: Where is your script.js located? Is it in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: @j08691 Oh, fixed that one now, and the console says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined." on line 9. And I am running it locally.

Comment: @StephRose Yeah, it's in the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a jQuery script locally and reference a CDN like Google, you need to change the URL to include the protocol. So change:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise the browser attempts to load the file from your local filesystem, usually with the file protocol `file://`

Comment: Thanks! First it was with the http: but then I saw other codes which all used the URL without the protocol, only it didn't work then because of a typo I had that was fixed now.

Comment: When you run your example on a web server, the protocol will be chosen automatically (http or https) so it's normally OK to leave it out. It's only when testing it locally that it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I am running it locally.

You need to run it from a local *webserver*.

Your URL to jQuery starts with `//` so it is relative to the current URL scheme.

If the HTML document is loaded over HTTP then jQuery will be loaded over HTTP. If it is loaded over HTTPS, then jQuery will be loaded over HTTPS. If it is loaded as a local file, then jQuery will be missing.

You *could* use an explicit URL scheme, but there are plenty of other things that work differently between pages loaded from a server and pages loaded from a local file, so you might as well get a local development server set up now.

Answer (score 0):

theres a `;` at the end of `"900px"` that should be removed. also, its more conventional to just put the function directly in `$(document).ready()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item").click(function(){
        $(".panel").animate({
            width:"900px"
        },600);
    });
});
```

```css
.panel {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="mosaic">
        <a href="#"><img class="item" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018721-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-smiley-face1.png"/></a>
        <img class="item" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018721-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-smiley-face1.png"/>
        <img class="item" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018721-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-smiley-face1.png"/>
        <img class="item" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018721-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-smiley-face1.png"/>
        <img class="item" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/glossy-black-icons-symbols-shapes/018721-glossy-black-icon-symbols-shapes-smiley-face1.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, another user pointed that typo out, though still, even with that fixed, the browser console says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined." on line 9.

Comment: @pandasticus, you didnt see my full code change....$(document).ready() should get rid of it. look at the demo